# Earphones voltages?

Tags: voltage

How much voltage is required for the earphones by which we listen voice and songs ? Please help with the calculations if possible??If we keep our earphones plugged with our mobile phones,do the battery gets discharged faster?

Comment: The meaningful part of this question is a duplicate.  Obviously any sane design for a battery powered audio device will not present a DC bias across a speaker (indeed, that is generally avoided regardless of the power source) so there should be next to no power consumption when not actually producing audio.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headphones&ei=UrJ17-UO&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=174&ts=1436104106&sig=AG8UcunnivMSbvZCzuXAwPxxkXXEU1H_rw

You can refer to this Article for calculation part under sensitivity section.
Regarding the discharge part I don't think plugging on would lead to higher battery drain because once earphone is plugged it bypasses the inbuilt speaker which consumes a lot more power than earphones.
I hope the answer is right.thanx

Comment: Most phones today do not have the earphone bypass the speaker, rather a second audio path becomes available but software selects between them (rings still go to the speaker typically), and when not producing audio *neither* is active.